# 80 million addresses. Index or partition?

Tags: mysql

I have a table(innodb) with ~80 million addresses(+phone). I'm going to be updating another table that contains ~750k records (phone and state) with the matching address. Seems like the best way to go would be grouping the data by state. Would indexing, or partitioning, be preferable in this situation? I've never worked with a dataset this large, so a few pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Also, once I've matched on phone/state, I'll probably need to circle back and attempt to rematch based only on phone to grab any phone/state mismatches.

Comment: Can't advise on index or partitioning choices without seeing more specifically what the query that you're trying to optimize looks like. Neither partitioning nor indexes make the *table* "faster" -- they are both for making specific *queries* faster.

Comment: @BillKarwin: He's "match(ing) on phone/state", so having an index on phone/state will be crucial to performance of this operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

80 million rows is not large for MySQL (or any modern RDBMS), assuming you are running on appropriate hardware.

I recommend applying appropriate indices.  Appropriate indices in this case would be one(s) that locate the row you are attempting to match by phone/state.  Partitioning should not be needed.

In any case, partitioning will not provide any performance benefit unless you have multiple, independent storage partitions (e.g. separate physical hard drives, etc).

On a side note, explore data quality before beginning the operation.  You may need to sanitize the data.  For example, one table may contain a given phone number as (234)555-1212 and the other may have it as 2345551212.

Comment: Already sanitized the phone to 10 digits only, so I'm good there. Your answer does make sense and was along the lines of what I thought would be the best approach. I just recently learned about partitioning. Seemed logical that breaking the data up by state should be faster than indexing. But when I tried with a moderate data set, it seemed horribly slow. But like you mentioned, that was on a single hd.

Comment: For the second match(phone only) would a phone(only) index be of any use at all? I try to stay away from indexing unique fields, as it would seem detrimental. Although, in practice, I have seen queries speed up using them which doesn't make a whole lot of sense.

Comment: @ScottHinton: Partitioning will be slower on a single HD, because you have all the overhead of partitioning with none of the benefit.  A unique index is very beneficial when you are matching rows based on that value.  If you do not have an index on the phone (and if it is not your primary key *not recommended*), you will perform a table scan for each row you match.  That is typically and orders of magnitude slower than an index match.